# how can I create a year column by counting month column? SAS

Tags: sas

I have dataset that looks like this. The date has 5 years starting from 07/01/2022.

```
id      date          qty
1   07/01/2022         0
1   08/01/2022         0
1   09/01/2022         0
1      ...
1   06/01/2027         0
```

how can I get my dataset to look like:

```
id      date          qty      year
1   07/01/2022         0        1
1   08/01/2022         0        1
1   09/01/2022         0        1
1      ...
1   06/01/2027         0        5
```

How can add a column 'year' for each 12 months

Comment: What is the logic for grouping dates as for ID=2 you have 2023 (first record as year=1, last record=2) as different years. Wouldn't it be easier to create a Year variable?

Comment: sorry for the mistake, I updated my question.

Comment: What do you mean for each 12 months? You don't show a full 12 months so it isn't clear when to increment a year. Is that a calendar that flips at each year (2022, 2023) or is it a fiscal year that starts in July? If calendar year, the answer below will get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a year variable instead.
Assuming the date is a SAS date, numeric with a format of mmddyy then it would be:

```
data want;
set have;
year = year(date);
yearNum = year-2022;
run;
```

Note that if the goal is to summarize by year, a [format works as well](https://gist.github.com/statgeek/0cae5568752959b035516d6ac07a20fb).